# PHP_Mailer won't print debug information

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I'm trying to send an email using PHP Mailer SMTP, however even after I turn on the SMTPDebug nothing is shown and I just get false when $Mail->send(),

this is what I have

```
$Mail = new PHPMailer();          
$Mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$Mail->IsSMTP(); 
$Mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$Mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$Mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; 
$Mail->Port = 587; 
$Mail->Priority = 1;
$Mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$Mail->Username = 'xxxxx@yyyyyyy.com';
$Mail->Password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$Mail->Encoding = '8bit';
$Mail->Subject = $subject;
$Mail->ContentType = 'text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n';
$Mail->From = "xxxxxxx@yyyyyyyyy.com";
$Mail->FromName = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$Mail->AddReplyTo($replyToEmail, $replyToName);
$Mail->WordWrap = 998; // RFC 2822 Compliant for Max 998 characters per line
$Mail->IsHTML(true);    
$Mail->body=$tpl;
$Mail->AddAddress($email);
$Mail->Send(); <------ false and doesn't print out why
```

I can't get the debug info to show up, does anyone know why?

Thanks

Comment: See if PHP's error reporting yields anything http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: `$Mail->Priority = 1; Normal, 5 = low)` if that's your real code, you should have gotten a parse error for this and for a few reasons. Are these comments even been read?

Comment: that was a comment I deleted when posting the question

Comment: I take posted code literally. If something looks out of sorts, then I comment. Didn't you use what I suggested you do?

Comment: It's not showing any errors because your'e not checking the return value of `send()` or looking at `ErrorInfo`, like all the examples do. Libraries should never generate spurious output unless asked to. If you are having trouble connecting at all (before any SMTP conversation) then SMTPDebug = 2 will show nothing - increase it to 3 for connection-level info, and [read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) that tell you all this and more. What Fred said too!

Comment: @Fred-ii- , I tried that but I was getting the same error, turned out to be $Mail->body , the b must be upper case in order to work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using an unmodified version of PHPMailer, then some of your property/method usages are using the incorrect case.  From the PHPMailer simple example available at https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer:

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Comment: Thank you Daniell, for doing the right thing when you're new here :)

Comment: Just trying to be helpful. I've lurked enough on SO over the years, it seemed long overdue to try and help someone out.  I guess case-sensitivity turned out to not be the problem somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Use try catch

```
try {
$Mail = new PHPMailer(true);   //<-- edit add true here        
$Mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$Mail->IsSMTP(); 
$Mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$Mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$Mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; 
$Mail->Port = 587; 
$Mail->Priority = 1; //Normal, 5 = low)
$Mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$Mail->Username = 'xxxxx@yyyyyyy.com';
$Mail->Password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$Mail->Encoding = '8bit';
$Mail->Subject = $subject;
$Mail->ContentType = 'text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n';
$Mail->From = "xxxxxxx@yyyyyyyyy.com";
$Mail->FromName = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$Mail->AddReplyTo($replyToEmail, $replyToName);
$Mail->WordWrap = 998; // RFC 2822 Compliant for Max 998 characters per line
$Mail->IsHTML(true);    
$Mail->body=$tpl;
$Mail->AddAddress($email);
$Mail->Send(); //<------ false and doesn't print out why
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage(); //Error from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(); //Other error messages
}
```

Comment: thanks but no exception is raised

Comment: PHPMailer doesn't raise exceptions unless you tell it to - pass `true` to the constructor.

Comment: true i didnt C/C well

Comment: @Synchro thanks, this helped me find the problem, the other people seemed more interested in complaining than actually help